# sqlite match all of many-to-one conditions

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm kind of a tyro with SQL, basic queries are fine but this has me stumped. I'm writing a simple photo organizer in node.js using sqlite where different tags are attached to photos to make them easy to find. A sample lookup might be to find photos with both me and my wife, taken in either San Francisco or LA. A photo table has (among other things) IDs and photo data, a tag table has tags, and a link table has rows linking foreign keys `(photoId, tagId)`. Assume tags for me and my wife have IDs 1 and 2, SF is 100, LA is 101, so I want to find all photo IDs that have tags (1 ***and*** 2) and (100 ***or*** 101). To get all photos from LA or SF is easy:

`SELECT photo.id FROM photo, link WHERE (photo.id = link.photoId) AND link.tagId IN (100, 101)`

To make a similar query for AND is trickier. I think the following should work, but is there a better way to do this?

`SELECT photo.id FROM photo INNER JOIN link ON photo.id = link.photoId WHERE link.tagId in (1, 2) GROUP BY photo.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;`

The link table has a unique constraint on `(photoId, tagId)` so the count should match the number of conditions.

I think this works, but seems a common enough pattern so there should be a better way. If I do this same type of query for each tag type (people, places, date, custom, ...) and intersect them is that the right way to do this? The database size isn't too large and usage will not be heavy so efficiency isn't vital, but I am hoping to use this opportunity to learn how to do things right with sql.

Thanks

Comment: This reference (http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/INTERSECT-td7103.html) is old, from 2009, but it describes what I want. It says: "I believe what you are looking for is the relational operator called DIVIDE, which is one of the original ones that E. F. Codd defined (along with (natural inner) JOIN, UNION, MINUS, PROJECT, RESTRICT, etc) but that very few if any SQL DBMSs actually implement directly, which is a crying shame.". It says there are ways to simulate it for small numbers of ids, but it doesn't scale well. So my solution is probably about as good as anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked again and it turns out no join is needed. The following query works - if someone sees it is not a good solution please comment so I can learn.

The table link sets up a many-to-many relationship between tags and photos:

```
CREATE TABLE `link` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `tag` INTEGER not null,
  `photo` INTEGER not null,
  UNIQUE(tag, photo)
  );
```

and the query is

`SELECT photo FROM link WHERE tag IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY photo HAVING count(*) = 3;`

(3 is the number of desired IDs in the IN group for this query)

Since the photo table is not needed (other information from it will come in another request) no join, and thus no view, is needed

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing u mean to say that you will be doing such type of query more often , so i would advice that you create a view on the columns that you need and then you should be able to find your answers faster that way.

> Like the photo_id and tag_id are in different table so instead of joining them every time you can create a view on them so you dont need to join them everytime.

Hope so you were searching for this. Ur welcome!

Comment: Thank you, while it doesn't directly answer my question it does help showing me how things are done, and gives a pointer on where I should direct my next readings. I had glanced at views before but not appreciated their connection to my problem.